# Powershell Executed Through C# / Unity, "Not Digitally Signed"

Tags: c#, powershell, unity-game-engine

I need to execute a PowerShell script with a passed string parameters from C#, for a Unity application.  I am attempting to use ProcessStartInfo and Process.Start calls, as follows:

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file \"{_path}\" -filePath \"{_filePath}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };
        Process test = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

However, I run into the error "The file
{the path}\command.ps1 is not digitally signed."

I have tried both "-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" and "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass", and neither removes this error when it's executed.  What might I be missing?

Comment: I have no explanation, but as an aside: `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` is the policy that normally _never_ refuses to run a script; `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` will still prompt for scripts downloaded from the web.

Comment: Is it the `_path` argument it's complaining about? At least hypothetically, the script you're invoking could be launching another PowerShell instance, which would _not_ inherit your original script's execution policy.

Comment: The _path argument points to the location of the script, and I do know that it's successfully finding the .ps1 script using that value.  The error doesn't give any information apart from the "not digitally signed" problem.